# how to solve program that sum of multiple number by 3 or 5 but only print number which is lower than its input

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, numbers

I wrote code like this using Python:

```
a = int(input("number = "))

def solution(a) :
    
    b = 1
    c = 0
    for b in range (1,a) :
        
        if b%3==0 or b%5==0 :
            c += b
            print("+",b,end=" ")
            
        if b>=a-1 :
            print("=",c)
            
solution(a)
```

But when I run this code it show's this:

```
number = 10
+ 3 + 5 + 6 + 9 = 23
```

How to delete + before number 3?

thank you

Comment: How did you add the `=` on the last iteration?  Do the same for the `+` on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
a = int(input("number = "))

def solution(a) :
    
    b = 1
    c = 0
    for b in range (1,a) :
        #For first iteration
        if c == 0:
          if b%3==0 or b%5==0 :
            c += b
            print(b,end=" ")

        #For remaining numbers
        if c>b and b%3==0 or b%5==0:
            c += b
            print("+",b,end=" ")
            
        if b>=a-1 :
            print("=",c)
            
solution(a)
```

Comment: Did it work? If so can you mark the answer as accepted please

Comment: yes it works thanks so much :)